# Signal handling with Queue in Ruby

Tags: ruby, multithreading, queue, signals

I am trying to do signal handling for my CLI app. I would like to avoid the self-pipe "trick", but also consider that using a per thread list of signals that is periodically polled is not the best idea. Hence, my idea was to use `Queue` to block until a new signal arrives. Here is my attempt:

```
class CLI
  def initialize
    @manager = Thread.new { sleep }
    @signal_queue = Queue.new

    setup_signal_handlers
  end

  def run
    loop do
      signal = @signal_queue.pop # This doesn't unblock!
      handle_signal(signal)
    end
  rescue Interrupt
    exit
  end

  private

  def handle_signal(signal)
    case signal
    when 'INT'
      raise Interrupt
    end
  end

  def setup_signal_handlers
    %w(INT).each do |signal|
      trap signal do
        @signal_queue.push signal # This works. @signal_queue.size is incremented
      end
    end
  end
end

# Run with CLI.new.run and hit ctrl^C
```

where I've simplified `@manager` for clarity. The problem is that, even if the signal is trapped and pushed to `@signal_queue`, the blocking call `@signal_queue.pop` doesn't pick it up. What am I missing here?

Comment: How do you run that code, where do you create your threads?

Comment: I run it simply with `CLI.new.run`. `@manager` creates a few long running threads.

Comment: Works fine for me ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @Stefan I have updated by example code with something simpler and easier to execute. I still have the same problem.

Comment: Still works for me ...

Comment: `! ruby -e 'require "./testing"; CLI.new.run'
^C` and it remains blocking there, as if nothing got pushed to the queue.

Comment: What can I say? It does work for me :-) Tested using `ruby 2.5.0p0 (2017-12-25 revision 61468) [x86_64-darwin15]` (that's macOS)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're experiencing Ruby bug [#12405: Queue doesn't work inside of trap](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/12405).  Luckily this bug got fixed in Ruby versions 2.2.7, 2.3.4, and 2.4.1 (2.5.0 already includes that fix); therefore your code behaves as expected after upgrading to a more recent Ruby version.

Comment: You are right! I was using ruby 2.4.0. Didn't imagine it was a problem in this version as well. Thanks for pointing this out!